# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';'

Tags: php, if-statement, syntax

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in index.php on line 310

Please Help! Where is the problem?

**Line 310**: `$getuidsfromcats = ;`

```
<?php

if ((isset($_GET['search']) && !empty($_GET['search'])))
    {
    $title = 'Search Result';
    $query_str = '?search=' . stripslashes(trim($_GET['search'])) . '&';
    $termnos = rtrim(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['search'])) , 's');
    $termwiths = rtrim(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_GET['search'])) , 's');
    $termwiths = $termwiths . 's';
    $searcharray = explode(' ', $termnos);
    foreach($searcharray as $word)
        {
        $searchboolean.= ' +' . $word;
        }

    $searchboolean = ltrim($searchboolean);
    mysql_query('SELECT uid
                FROM hostedgals_cats c
                WHERE c.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or c.name like \'' . $termwiths . '\'');
    $getuidsfromcats =;
    mysql_query('SELECT cat_id
                FROM category_matches m
                WHERE m.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or  m.name LIKE \'' . $termwiths . '\'');
    $getuidsfrommatchcats =;
    if (0 < mysql_num_rows($getuidsfromcats))
        {
        $cat_id = mysql_result($getuidsfromcats, 0, 'uid');
        $catquery = 34;
        }
      else
        {
        if (0 < mysql_num_rows($getuidsfrommatchcats))
            {
            $cat_id = mysql_result($getuidsfrommatchcats, 0, 'cat_id');
            $catquery = 34;
            }
          else
            {
            $catquery = 33;
            }
        }
```

Thank you guys!!!

Comment: you need something after the =

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. Here is a good [tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ) for PDO.

Comment: If you want the string to be blank, use `$getuidsfrommatchcats = '';` or `... = null;`

Comment: What do you want to achieve in this line: `$getuidsfromcats = ;` ? Set the variable to null ?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the errors:

```
mysql_query( 'SELECT uid
            FROM hostedgals_cats c
            WHERE c.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or c.name like \'' . $termwiths . '\'' );
$getuidsfromcats = ;
mysql_query( 'SELECT cat_id
            FROM category_matches m
            WHERE m.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or  m.name LIKE \'' . $termwiths . '\'' );
$getuidsfrommatchcats = ;
```

You should be assigning those variables with the results of the calls, so it they should be:

```
$getuidsfromcats = mysql_query( 'SELECT uid
            FROM hostedgals_cats c
            WHERE c.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or c.name like \'' . $termwiths . '\'' );
$getuidsfrommatchcats = mysql_query( 'SELECT cat_id
            FROM category_matches m
            WHERE m.name LIKE \'' . $termnos . '\' or  m.name LIKE \'' . $termwiths . '\'' );
```